# Matlab functionSignatures.json not working

Tags: matlab

I made a functionSignatures.json file to go along with a user function, however, Matlab will not use it for tab completion. Instead, it is just using the standard information from the function prototype. I used `validateFunctionSignaturesJSON` to validate there were no errors in the JSON, and the functionSignatures.json file is in the same directory and the function's m file.

I assume I must be missing something, but I have followed the tutorials on Matlab's website. The following is the JSON file for reference.

Currently using Matlab 2019a if that matters

```
{
    "_schemaVersion": "1.0.0",
    "dc":
    {
        "inputs":
        [
            {"name":"M","kind":"required","type":"2d"},
            {"name":"C","kind":"required","type":"integer"},
            {"name":"S","kind":"ordered","type":"choices={0,3,6,11}"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem of "not working"? It may worth to check your dc.m file. The .json file is good and it works for me.

Comment: Not working means the json file isn't being used. I have tried changing the argument names between the json and function prototype to see which is used (never the json). I have more complicated examples with mutually exclusive inputs that never display as expected. Matlab always defaults to using the function prototype and never the information from the json file.